# Criteria, projections, ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP 

Tags: java, hibernate

I've go two entities with bidirectional onetomany associtaion. I want to use criteria with projections(to get data only from few columns) to get many `Person`s with many `Adress`es. Result from query I want to put into `List<Map<String, Object>>`. Resulted list should have this structure(address data should be a `List<Map<String, Object>>` contained in parent address object):

```
[
   {
     name: "Andrew"
     surname: "..."
     adress : [
        {
            city : "New York"
            street : "..."
            type : "home"
        }
        {
            city : "..."
            street : "..."
            type : "work:
        }
     ]
  { 
     name: "..."
     surname : "..."
     address : [{....}]
   }
]
```

Entities:

```
public class Person{
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private String surname;
     private Integer age;
     private String phoneNr;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<Address> addresses

    // getters and setters
}


public class Address{
     private Long id;
     private String city;
     private String street;
     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
     private Person person;


     // getters and setters
}
```

All I could achieve was to load whole entities, what does not meet my needs.

```
Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(Person.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("addresses", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to return a `List<Map<String, Object>>` from query. 
The easiest way to get structure that you want is to create it manually (at least I think so):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> resultsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
List<Person> persons = criteria.list();

for (Person person: persons) {
   resultsList.put("name", person.getName());
   resultsList.put("surname", person.getSurname());
   List<Map<Strin, Object>> addressesList = new ArrayList<Map<Strin, Object>>();
   for(Address address: person.getAddresses()) {
       addressesList.put("city", address.getCity());
       addressesList.put("street", address.getStreet());
       addressesList.put("type", address.getType());   
   }
   resultsList.put("name", person.ngetName());
}
```

After this *resultsList* will contain structure that you need.

Comment: It is possible to return a `List<Map<String, Object>>` from query.

By doing as you wrote, I fetch all entity from database(what I don't want to do) and I probably have many database queries one per `Person` to fetch `Adress`es.